# Extracting Specific record from webservice XML

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, browser

How would i go about extracting specific information from the XML returned from a webservice.

The webservice is called from an embedded webbrowser in a C# windows form.

I was thinking that mabey i could save the displayed data as XML file and read from that though it would need to be automatic and not use the save dialog that webbrowser control has.

I was also thinking that i could read from the browser and load as xmlDocument.

If anyone could point me in the right direction here it would really help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is there are reason you are using an embedded webbrowser instead of a WebRequest?
Using a WebRequest getting the sourcecode would be trivial.

I think the ActiveX internet explorer control had a string property containing the sourcecode which should be what you want.

Comment: Hmm thats a good point i could use WebRequest, the browser needs to be embedded for the tool, however i dont necessarily need to use the browser for this specific task. i shall look into this thanks.